# R parallelise script for loading multiple .cvs.gz file and computing column mean per group

Tags: r, multithreading, dataframe, parallel-processing, data.table

I am trying to parallelise a process in R for loading and calculating the mean value of
a column per group for 8 .csv.gz files.

Based on similar posts, I have tried the following code but it seems normal loop vs parallel takes similar time
I am using a Mac book Pro with 8 cores.

```
paths<- c(p1,p2,p3,...,p8) # paths to .gz files


# Function for normal loop
f1 <- function(i) {
  s1<-fread(i, head=T, sep="\t", skip=skip, verbose=FALSE)
  aggregate(s1$X, list(s1$Chr), FUN=mean) 
}

# Function for parallel process
f2 <- function(i) {
  s1<-fread(paths[i], head=T, sep="\t", skip=skip, verbose=FALSE)
  aggregate(s1$X, list(s1$Chr), FUN=mean) 
}

benchmark(
  'loop'={for (path in paths[1:8]){f1(path)}
  },
  
  'mapply'={system.time(save1 <- mapply(1:8, FUN=f2))
  },
  
  replications = 20,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
              "relative", "user.self", "sys.self")
)
```

Output:

```
    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1   loop           20 906.714    1.574   303.566   56.142
2 mapply           20 575.990    1.000   303.854   54.061
```

Comment: `mapply` is sequential, not parallel. There is no reason its runtime should be different from the `for` loop. If you want truly parallel, look into the `parallel` package (and/or `future` or one of several helper packages that do truly multi-process work in R); however, if your files are large (suggested by the drive to parallelize multiple-file-reads), then while reading them might be done in parallel, you will still have an overhead of transferring large data from the other process into the current one. I'm not sure how that will balance out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the runtimes are similar is that `data.table::fread` is already parallelized using `OpenMP` and `mapply` is not parallelizing per se.

This example also shows the common misconception that `for` loops are slow in `R` which is not true anymore (it was though in older versions of `R`).

To further speed up your code you can utilize `data.table` syntax, e.g.

```
f3 <- function(i) {
  s1<-fread(i, head=T, sep="\t", skip=skip, verbose=FALSE)
  s1[, mean(X), Chr]
}
```